# Running a function using threading and storing its return value to be used later

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I am trying to have a function that gets the name of a newly downloaded file run in the background while I run another program that downloads a specific file. The background function will have a return value of the newly downloaded file which I plan to utilize in the code later on. I have the rough framework of what I am trying to do below.

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = 1) as executor:
     output = executor.submit(downloadedfiledetector, filedirectory)
     filename = output.result()
#Run code that will download a file
print(filename)
```

Here, downloadedfiledetector is the function that returns the directory of the file that is downloaded and filedirectory is the argument to that function containing the file path that the function will watch. I want the return value to be stored in the filename variable so that I can then utilize it later on in the program. Then below that, I run more code that essentially downloads a file from a website where the name of the file will be different everytime (hence the need for a function that grabs the name of a newly downloaded file).

When I run the above code, it simply does not run the code that downloads the file and only runs the downloadedfiledetector function. Any help is appreciated!

Edit:
I was asked to include a working example of the code. I know it is for sure not the best way to do this, but I wrote it myself (for the most part) and I'm still pretty new to Python. At the bottom of the code, the combinesubtitletovideo function is where I will use the downloaded .srt file and combine it with a video:

```
import os
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import undetected_chromedriver as bypass
import concurrent.futures

def downloadedfiledetector(scannedfolder, variablefunction):
    seconds = 0
    dl_wait = True
    filelist1 = []
    filelist2 = []
    while dl_wait and seconds < 120:
        for fname in os.listdir(scannedfolder):
            filelist1.append(fname)
            if fname.endswith('.crdownload') and seconds != 0:
                filelist1.pop()
        time.sleep(1)
        for fname in os.listdir(scannedfolder):
            filelist2.append(fname)
            if fname.endswith('.crdownload') and seconds != 0:
                filelist2.pop()
        if seconds != 0 and len(filelist1) != len(filelist2):
            dl_wait = False
        seconds += 1
    if variablefunction == 1:
        newfilename1 = list(set(filelist2) - set(filelist1))
        newfilename2 = ''.join(str(e) for e in newfilename1)
        time.sleep(1)
        driver.close()
        return newfilename2
    elif variablefunction == 2:
        pass

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = 1) as executor:
    output = executor.submit(downloadedfiledetector, cliplocation, 1)
    filenamesubtitle = output.result()
driver = bypass.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(subtitleurl)
WebDriverWait(driver, 300).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#root > section > section.container.mx-auto.py-6.mt-4.sm\:mt-6 > div.mx-auto.max-w-4xl.leading-normal.mt-6.sm\:mt-10.sm\:flex.justify-center.px-4.lg\:px-0.text-center > div > div > div > input')))
enterurlbox = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#root > section > section.container.mx-auto.py-6.mt-4.sm\:mt-6 > div.mx-auto.max-w-4xl.leading-normal.mt-6.sm\:mt-10.sm\:flex.justify-center.px-4.lg\:px-0.text-center > div > div > div > input')
enterurlbox.send_keys(youtubeurl)
WebDriverWait(driver, 300).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#root > section > section.container.mx-auto.py-6.mt-4.sm\:mt-6 > div.mx-auto.max-w-4xl.leading-normal.mt-6.sm\:mt-10.sm\:flex.justify-center.px-4.lg\:px-0.text-center > button')))
downloadbutton = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#root > section > section.container.mx-auto.py-6.mt-4.sm\:mt-6 > div.mx-auto.max-w-4xl.leading-normal.mt-6.sm\:mt-10.sm\:flex.justify-center.px-4.lg\:px-0.text-center > button')
downloadbutton.click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 300).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#root > section > main > section.max-w-3xl.mx-auto.md\:flex.md\:justify-between.pt-4 > div.w-full.px-4.lg\:px-0.mb-6.md\:mb-0 > ul > li.py-6.text-center.block.w-full.px-2.sm\:px-4.sm\:py-3.sm\:flex.justify-between.items-center.border-b.border-gray-200.dark\:border-night-500 > section > div > div > a:nth-child(1)')))
srtdownloadbutton = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#root > section > main > section.max-w-3xl.mx-auto.md\:flex.md\:justify-between.pt-4 > div.w-full.px-4.lg\:px-0.mb-6.md\:mb-0 > ul > li.py-6.text-center.block.w-full.px-2.sm\:px-4.sm\:py-3.sm\:flex.justify-between.items-center.border-b.border-gray-200.dark\:border-night-500 > section > div > div > a:nth-child(1)')
srtdownloadbutton.click()
time.sleep(2)
combinesubtitletovideo(filenamesubtitle)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and create a working code example of what you are experiencing.

Comment: I'm confused.  If the "downloadedfiledetector" function is running and returning a result, which you are using, then the multithreading part of your program is already working.  If the problem is that the code to download the file is not working, shouldn't you be asking a question about that, instead of about multithreading?  What am I missing?

Comment: Yes, the downloadedfiledetector function is running, however it is halting the execution of the subsequent code. The subsequent code works just fine without the downloadedfiledetector function running before it, in which that code's sole purpose is to download a file that the aforementioned function will read. So, the multithreading here isn't functioning properly since I need the original function to be running while the subsequent code is executed.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  You are not actually doing multithreading: you launch `downloadedfiledetector` in another thread but immediately wait for it to be finished by calling output.result().  So the main thread is blocked until the second one returns.  You need to split your program into two functions and run both of them in different  secondary threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone has come across this or is having similar issues, I solved my own problem. It of course didn't take me a few months to solve, however I thought I would share my process here just in case anyone else may find it useful.

I shouldn't have been using the concurrent futures library, I should have instead been using the threading library. The code actually becomes much, much simpler and easy to comprehend this way:

```
import threading, os, time

output_file = [] #We innitialize this variable as a list. This will contain the output for the threaded function, as there is not an easy way (to my knowledge at least) to get the return value of a function. Thus, by appending the output of the threaded function to this list, we can access that output outside of the threaded function.

def downloaded_file_detector(scanned_folder, variable_function):
    #input code for detecting the downloaded file. The psuedocode is as follows:
    global output_file #This part may or may not be necessary
    
    while True:
        before_folder_contents = os.listdir(scanned_folder) #create a list of all filenames
        time.sleep(1) #allow for the file download to take place within the interval of 1 second
        after_folder_contents = os.listdir(scanned_folder)
        
        if len(before_folder_contents) != len(after_folder_contents):
            modified_file = ... #here, we perform some function that gets the changed file, i.e. the added element between the two lists
            output_file.append(modified_file)
            break
            
def download_file():
    #I will not write it out in full, but this is the function that downloads a file. It will end once the file has been downloaded.
    
thread_download_detector = threading.Thread(target=downloaded_file_detector, args=(scanned_folder, variable_function))
thread_download_file = threading.Thread(target=download_file)
thread_download_detector.start()
thread_download_file.start()

#The following block of code will effectively pause execution until the threads have completed
while True:
    if len(output_file) != 0:
        break
    else:
        time.sleep(1) #check to see if the two threads have completed ever 1 second
```

Alternatively, you may use a threading.Event object and set it once one of your threaded functions has stopped running in order to see when to check for the downloaded file. This is probably the more efficient/"pythonic" way of doing things.

I hope this helps anyone who comes across this problem in the future. For this sort of work, please look into the threading library and threading.Event objects, as those are the best ways (in my experience) to communicate between multiple subsequently-running processes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use map functionality that returns the result from the target function :

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = 1) as executor:
     for result in executor.map(downloadedfiledetector, filedirectory):
        print(result) #this gives you the required return value from function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
import os
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import undetected_chromedriver as bypass
import concurrent.futures

def downloadedfiledetector(scannedfolder, variablefunction):
    pass # Code exactly like your example, omitted for clarity

def subsequent():
    driver = bypass.Chrome(options=options)
    # Your same code...
    srtdownloadbutton.click()
    # Remove time.sleep() at the end, it does nothing

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = 1) as executor:
    output1 = executor.submit(downloadedfiledetector, cliplocation, 1)
    output2 = executor.submit(subsequent)
    filenamesubtitle = output1.result()
    output2.result()

combinesubtitletovideo(filenamesubtitle)
```

This will execute both functions in parallel in 2 different threads.  The main thread waits for both of them; the order in which they finish doesn't matter.  Once both threads have finished (returned a result) the main thread continues.